# Pixel size for clips in retro NES-like game?

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm making a retro videogame, currently I'm using 32px x 32px tiles for the map and 64px x 32px for the characters.

However the game looks extremely small, I could increase the tile size to something like 64px but it seems dumb since I would have to scale all the images (I don't care about adding more definition for the characters than this).

So my question is, should I increase the tile sizes or do it in 32px and zoom/scale the images depending on screen size? Is this how games like Super Mario Bros. do it?

Comment: How can we give a meaningful answer to your question? Based on the goals of your project, your budget and your interests, the only one who can answer that is yourself!

Comment: @PandaPajama I don't agree that this is unanswerable.  Retro graphics are a pretty common style with established techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion: Zoom/Scale the image.

Reasoning:

The NES and SNES zoom/scale the image to the screen. The games, however, never needed to. They had a number of sprites they could use, that where a fixed width/height. Those sprites would be referenced to and placed throughout the larger image, which was the resulting image for the game screen. If you recall the size of those pixels, it was a small image (It sound's like you have a similar image.) That image was *automatically* stretched across the screen for the gamer to see.

Just increasing the tile size wouldn't be enough. If that's how you go about it, then when it's rendered on a bigger screen, the whole thing just becomes small again. On top of that, if you aren't going to use the extra detail, then it's a wast of resources, Having more pixels to process, needing more RAM to store it, and the moment the Computer monitor get's bigger/higher-res your game becomes a tiny little picture again.

Comment: I changed all my tiles to 32px, I have one question regarding this and scaling. Since all my images are pretty small when I scale them they look horribly blurry, is there a way to get around this? I remember playing NES games and you just saw pixels as big blocks, this is what I want to do. Any info will be useful. I'm working with SDL by the way

Comment: The blur would be due to some form of interpolation (Probably linear interpolation.) Ideally, you would want a nearest interpolation method. That would give you the pixelaited look. I'm not familiar with SDL, and cant find anything online, so your on your own for finding out how to do that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Two parts: you don't need to scale up your source assets, and you don't need to scale them based on screen size.

First, your assets may be drawn at any size on screen; they aren't limited to their own resolution.  Their appearance when scaled is a function of how they are sampled by the graphics hardware while rendering a 2D quad.  If you want the retro look, that implies that you want them to retain their "pixelyness" when scaled up.  The method for that is 
[nearest-neighbor interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering#Nearest-neighbor_interpolation).

That wikipedia is pretty sparse, but the general idea is that each element in the pixel shader takes its color from one and only one pixel in the source texture, rather than an interpolation of multiple close pixels (which would result in a blurry image).  i.e., the source is not antialiased.

Here's an example.  Disregard the rotated and re-scaled images, this was taken from a mostly unlreated  [blog article about texture sampling by Shawn Hargreaves](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/04/29/texture-aliasing.aspx), the former XNA project lead. 
[image]

I don't know what the equivalent SDL setting would be, perhaps commenters can fill in that blank for me.  But in XNA, this is accomplished by setting the texture sampler state to `SamplerState.PointClamp`, which is a high-level abstraction of a config options for the graphics hardware.

The second part of my answer is about scaling to screen size.  I don't think you should do this on a per-sprite basis.  You *might* need to scale the whole rendering of your game to match screen resolution, but this should be independent from your individual tiles.  Your tiles should be scaled relative to your game window, not the screen itself.  I think this distinction is important; you don't want to have to detect screen size for every tile you draw.

It would be better to draw an item at an appropriate size in world coordinates, and scale your camera's view to show it in proper proportion to the screen.

#### Edit: one good example

In the [The Platformance:...](http://www.magikogaming.com/Games/CastlePain/) games, the zoom levels show all the same graphics, but at varying zoom levels.  Close up, the images are intentionally blocky.  But in the wide view, they appear like any other 2d art.

[image: castle pain close up]
[image: castle pain wide]